# Does Flutter Firebase Mlkit need a Firebase project?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Do you have to link a Firebase project just to use local image processing using Mlkit?

Comment: have you try it? the docs says you have to add android project to firebase console. simply, if it not working without linking it, so the answer is no. When I use MLKit for my project, I create and link it to firebase, even for a local processing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a Firebase project to be able to use any of the Firebase SDKs effectively.